# Visual Studio's Find All References. How does that work?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-navigation

Visual Studio has a couple of great features:

- Find All References
- View Call Hierarchy

I'd like to understand how these tools work.  What are they using to efficiently identify the references to the method in question?  Presumably it's not using Reflection.

Can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: Think I found the answer.....I'm working my way through Josh Varty's series "Learn Roslyn Now" on YouTube.  Good Stuff!

Comment: Note that Roslyn is only for .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, etc.). Roslyn is not used for C or C++ development.